# Do an action when conditions are met

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone I am new to android/java programming and I have the following question:

I take some variables, say a,b and c from a `function` that refresh at a constant rate. What I need is something to happen when these variables pass some thresholds. Let's say:

```
if(a>b and c>0){
//do procedure A
}
```

PLUS I want procedure A to be active while the previous conditions are met and turn off when they are not. Can you give me a hint on what functions/classes/tools to use?

Comment: You can use an if statement, but refreshing at a constant rate may be more complex than you need

Comment: How often the variables changes? If not much you can send broadcast and always check for all conditions.

Comment: @skywall the variables change every 0.001 sec, so it's pretty much i guess.